# How to read a file from a relative path in Jdeveloper ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, backing-beans

I want to read a file from a relative path in my Jdeveloper Adf project, I have my files in a path like this "\ProjectName\ViewController\public_html\files", my file is an image, so what can I do?, I want to my code to work in any server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my answer will be useful for others,

I have read the file using code like the following,

```
        ServletContext servletCtx = ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();


        InputStream inputStream = servletCtx.getResourceAsStream("/images/image.png");
```

The path for my project and resurces is something like this

"\ProjectName\ViewController\public_html\images"

Regards.